# Scanning two QRCodes in the same camera frame

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm currently using SwiftQRCode reader to scan my QR codes however, I was wondering if it was possible to scan two QR codes within the same camera frame. The information needed to decode is stored within two QR codes.

Is there a way to produce two scan boxes that scan and then store both the information within one string to be returned to my main controller?

```
public func prepareScan(view: UIView, completion:(stringValue: String)->()) {

    scanFrame = view.bounds

    completedCallBack = completion
    currentDetectedCount = 0

    setupSession()
    setupLayers(view)
}

/// start scan
public func startScan() {
    if session.running {
        print("the  capture session is running")

        return
    }
    session.startRunning()
}

/// stop scan
public func stopScan() {
    if !session.running {
        print("the capture session is not running")

        return
    }
    session.stopRunning()
}

func setupLayers(view: UIView) {
    drawLayer.frame = view.bounds
    view.layer.insertSublayer(drawLayer, atIndex: 0)
    previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, atIndex: 0)
}

func setupSession() {
    if session.running {
        print("the capture session is running")
        return
    }

    if !session.canAddInput(videoInput) {
        print("can not add input device")
        return
    }

    if !session.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
        print("can not add output device")
        return
    }

    session.addInput(videoInput)
    session.addOutput(dataOutput)

    dataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = dataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes;
    dataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
}

public func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    clearDrawLayer()

    for dataObject in metadataObjects {

        if let codeObject = dataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject,
            obj = previewLayer.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(codeObject) as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {

            if CGRectContainsRect(scanFrame, obj.bounds) {
                currentDetectedCount = currentDetectedCount + 1
                if currentDetectedCount > maxDetectedCount {
                    session.stopRunning()

                    completedCallBack!(stringValue: codeObject.stringValue)

                    if autoRemoveSubLayers {
                        removeAllLayers()
                    }
                }

                // transform codeObject
                drawCodeCorners(previewLayer.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(codeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject)
            }
        }
    }
}

public func removeAllLayers() {
    previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    drawLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}

func clearDrawLayer() {
    if drawLayer.sublayers == nil {
        return
    }

    for layer in drawLayer.sublayers! {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}

func drawCodeCorners(codeObject: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) {
    if codeObject.corners.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.path = createPath(codeObject.corners).CGPath

    drawLayer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

func createPath(points: NSArray) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    var point = CGPoint()

    CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((points[0] as! CFDictionary), &point)
    path.moveToPoint(point)

    var index = 1
    while index < points.count {

        CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((points[index] as! CFDictionary), &point)
        path.addLineToPoint(point)

        index = index + 1
    }
    path.closePath()

    return path
}

/// previewLayer
lazy var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
    let layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    return layer
    }()

/// drawLayer
lazy var drawLayer = CALayer()
/// session
lazy var session = AVCaptureSession()
/// input
lazy var videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput? = {

    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        return try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
    }
    return nil
    }()

/// output
lazy var dataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
```

}

Comment: I guess you're probably asking specifically if this can be done using `SwiftQRCode`. I haven't use  SwiftQRCode so I don't know. But if you're not limited to `SwiftQRCode` the answer is yes. But would suggest to make some research and ask more specific question, as otherwise it would be too broad.

Comment: I just happened to be using SwiftQRCode, I'm just not too clear on how to make the program detect one QR code, save that string and continue to read for a second QR code within the same camera frame. Would I have to create separate variables for each QR code or am I able to use just one function to decode both QR codes?